# Dynamics 365 REST Builder - RouteTo function not working

Tags: javascript, rest, dynamics-crm

I am trying to use RouteTo function through Dynamics CRM REST Builder Tool.  When I am trying to execute this request, getting a data type error.

### JSON Sent in request:

{"Target":{"primarykeyid":"{304CEAA4-B748-E811-A950-000D3A3606DE}","@odata.type":"Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser"},"QueueItem":{"primarykeyid":"{976af0fa-9712-e911-a981-000d3a360e00}","@odata.type":"Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.queueitem"}}

### Error Message:

{"error":{"code":"0x0","message":"An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Does not support untyped value in non-open type.\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.DeserializationHelpers.ApplyProperty(ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredTypeReference resourceType, Object resource, ODataDeserializerProvider deserializerProvider, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperties(Object resource, ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.CrmODataEntityDeserializer.ApplyStructuralProperties(Object resource, ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.ReadResource(ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.ReadResource(ODataResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmODataActionPayloadDeserializer.ReadEntry(ODataDeserializerContext readContext, ODataParameterReader reader, IEdmOperationParameter parameter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.CrmODataActionPayloadDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext

I already tried capitalizing the schema names, adding/removing {} brackets around GUIDs.

function route() {

```
var parameters = {};
var target = {};
target.primarykeyid = "304CEAA4-B748-E811-A950-000D3A3606DE";
target["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser";
parameters.Target = target;
var queueitem = {};
queueitem.primarykeyid = "976af0fa-9712-e911-a981-000d3a360e00";
queueitem["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.queueitem";
parameters.QueueItem = queueitem;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/RouteTo", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

}

This request should be executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want your `QueueItem` to have a `queueitemid` property (not a `primarykeyid`).

```js
var parameters = {};
var target = {};
target.primarykeyid = "304CEAA4-B748-E811-A950-000D3A3606DE";
target["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser";
parameters.Target = target;

var queueitem = {};
queueitem.queueitemid = "976af0fa-9712-e911-a981-000d3a360e00";
queueitem["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.queueitem";
parameters.QueueItem = queueitem;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/RouteTo", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};

req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```